# Kali Linux black screen with blinking cursor after USB boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, dual-boot, kali-linux

I am using a Macbook Air (2013) with Intel HD Graphics 5000. I made a USB to live-boot into Kali and install it onto a separate partition, essentially dual boot my Yosemite (OSX 10.10) with Kali Linux. I am using rEFInd to load the live USB, and am able to get to the screen that asks me to choose what to load (Live amd64, Live forensic mode, install, graphic install, etc). Every option that I choose leads me to a black screen with a blinking cursor after these two lines appear on the screen: `Loading /live/vmlinuz... ok` and `Loading /live/initrd.img... ok`. The cursor keeps blinking, and nothing appears to happen. I have tried adding `nomodeset` to the boot options of some of the choices (after hitting tab and appending 'nomodeset' to the end) to no avail, and am really stuck on what to do. Each of the other questions regarding this are different from my specifications.

Comment: Does a MacBook implement SecureBoot??

Comment: Not exactly sure, actually (from this, I would assume no). I am using EFI, however, for the boot process. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Can you see if you can disable SecureBoot in your BIOS?

Comment: MacBook's don't have BIOS, unfortunately. As previously said, I am using EFI (somewhat of a BIOS replacement that isn't directly accessible)

Comment: Try a [YellowDog Live Disc](http://www.fixstars.com/en/technologies/linux/downloads/)

Comment: Is it a type of Linux? I'm looking to install Kali Linux only.

Comment: I know, but YellowDog was written for a Mac.  I need to know if the LiveDisk Works

Comment: Many people have dual boot Macbook Airs, and I was following several well known tutorials (including the one from the official Kali page, link upon request). My Kali USB runs fine until I choose a boot type. If this still does't help, then I shall try YellowDog when I get the opportunity (probably sometime tomorrow) and post back.

Comment: The reason its not Workinh for Kali is that a MacBook only uses EFI, and you need to use a Grub2 with EFI Support or choose YaBoot, which is the trusted default

Comment: I see, but the newest distro of Kali, 1.0.9 has full support for EFI?

Comment: Is your [checksum correct](http://www.kali.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Rufus to create the image and had the same error. I used Win32 Disk Imager and problem solved..
http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: I did the same a couple days back, forgot this thread is here x)
I'll mark this correct!

Answer (score 0):

okay

1. when you get the black screen and cursor blinking press ALT + F2
2. login with your root account
3. update packages

   ```
   apt-get install --fix-broken
   apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade
   ```
4. reboot

that should do it